# Maintain Many to Many References

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have a product that I am trying to associate categories to.  The list of categories is static.  I have set up a bi-directional many-to-many relationship up between `Product` and `Category` using `Set<?>` properties like so:

```
class Product {

  @ManyToMany
  public Set<Category> categories;

}

class Category {

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
  public Set<Product> products;

}
```

I would like certain users to maintain this relationship, but the only previous way I have seen is to just use a `List<Long>` to pass back to the controller and add appropriately.  This works fine until the user needs to edit these mappings.  I have tried clearing the relationship, but that doesn't prove to be simple either.

Is there a decent way to maintain this relationship?  If my only option is to "loop and delete" the references, can someone point me in the right direction how to do so appropriately?  So far my failed attempts look like this:

```
for(Category category : product.categories) {
  category.products.remove(product);
}
```

and

```
Category.delete("categories.id = ?", product.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintaining the relationship: Yes, passing the IDs to the controller and fetching the entities there is okay.

The relationship proper, there are some things to note:

First, you need to set the `cascade` annotation, without it nothing in the assocation will get deleted:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Category> categories;
```

Second, one Entity is the owner of the relation. In your case it's correctly set as the `Product` class (as the `Category`class uses `mappedBy`). Updates only reflect when done on the owner, so to remove all categories from a product you would do

```
products.categories = new Set<Product>();
```

if you want to remove a single categorie, just remove it from the `products.categories`.